# Scan over Wifi with HP MFP from Debian Server

Tags: debian, scanner, hp

I try to use the Scanner of a "HP Color Laser MFP 178nw" on a Debian Server in a different network. I can use the scanner on my Laptop if it is in the same network via Airprint. I tried different approaches (cups, hplip "scanimage -L") to set it up with no success. Is there any chance to solve that?